# UITextField text colour goes invisible when editing - is this a bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITableView which is set up to resemble drawing on a blackboard. The cells contain a UITextField which has the `textColor` property set to a pattern image:

```
textField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chalkTexture.png"]];
```

This all works fine. However, the cell is editable in-place, and doing this makes the text invisible! I have removed all possible background items so I know it isn't being overlapped by anything, or drawing black on a black background, for example.

I can "solve" the problem by changing the text colour  in my delegate methods like so:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chalkTexture.png"]];
}
```

This doesn't look too bad and does emphasise the cell that is being edited, but I'd like to keep the textured colour for my text. Is this a bug or intentional behaviour?

Comment: Yes, the behaviour is really strange. I would say it is a bug.