# Why doesn't an editable Cocoa text field cell draw a shadow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

So, it works fine if I disable editing for the textfield/textfieldcell... through code or interface builder.

[image] (notice the slight shadow)

But once I make it editable ([cell setEditable:YES]) the shadow completely disappears:

[image]

I've tried drawing a shadow two ways: One, setting `NSBackgroundStyleRaised`, and two, overriding `- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView` to manually create a shadow. Both styles/ways of drawing a shadow stop working once the cell is made editable. (To make it clear, the end result should be inset-looking, editable text. The pictures above only served as a demonstration.)

Can someone tell me why? And how I can get around this issue?

Comment: Interesting, wonder if it is part of the same issue in iOS, see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444473/uitextfield-text-colour-goes-invisible-when-editing-is-this-a-bug . Perhaps when any text field becomes editable, fancy drawing gets turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out why, at least partially -

Because I was using `- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView` to set the shadow, and because when editing, the [field editor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html) is also doing the drawing (and it's not going through the above mentioned method) the shadow doesn't apply to it.

Confirmation on this might be nice, but for now I'm going to assume this is why the shadow isn't drawing.